# Loan Account Status Codes

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

I'm unable to find a list of status codes in documentation, we found them for AcctAdd in the provider section for Silverlake as AcctAddStatusCodes, but no list found for LnAcctAdd or specific provider info.

We want to ensure we're not listing loans that are not active (or otherwise shouldn't be seen in our application).

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in this documentation:

https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-assets/cms-files/soap/JXchangeAndSilverLake.pdf

Loan Status Codes Status (1.0)
The default status code will be obtained from the type code parameter file. In new loan entry, in most cases, this code should be 4 to indicate a new loan today. Other valid codes are:

1 - The loan is active. Transactions will be accepted.
2 - The loan is closed. Transactions will not be accepted.
3 - The loan is matured. The system will not allow advances to post.
4 - The loan is new today. Transactions will be accepted.
5 - The loan is open but not accruing. Transactions will be accepted.
6 - The loan is accruing, but frozen. Transactions will not be accepted.
7 - The loan is frozen and not accruing. Transactions will not be accepted.
8 - The loan is charged off. It is not accruing. Transactions will be accepted.

The status code should be left at 4 for all new loans. The ability to enter status codes 5, 6, 7, and 8 is
provided primarily for the purpose of adding charged off loans to the system after conversion. Some
servicing companies do not carry charged off loans in their database, and they are not converted to the
JHA system.